# Is it possible to have the same URL serve a different website on a different port?

Tags: nginx

Using NGINX and trying to redirect traffic using the same URL but traveling on another port to a different website.

Is this possible:

```
server {
  listen 80
  server_name myurl.com;
}
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name myurl.com:8080;
}
```

Comment: The URL would be different if the port were different. Do you mean hostname instead? If so then yes, it's possible (but you don't include the port in `server_name`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

I don't think you can include the port number in the `server_name` directive (such syntax is not mentioned anywhere on the official site), so, try this instead, it should work:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name example.org;
}
server {
    listen *:8080;
    server_name example.org;
}
```